# IPython %run vs. import for loading settings

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm unable to find anything meaningful by searching these keywords, so I'm asking here.

What is the main difference between *IPython*'s (when running in a *Jupyter notebook*) `%run` and *Python*'s `import`? If I'd like to import some settings (say, for *Matplotlib*), for multiple notebooks, which one shall I use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems I'm a bit late to the party...
For me the most meaningful  difference between using `import` and `%run` is felt when developing packages, [form the docs](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/tutorial.html): "Since the file is re-read from disk each time [ when using `%run` ] , changes you make to it are reflected immediately (unlike imported modules, which have to be specifically reloaded)"

In practice this means that I need to restart the notebook kernel when I make changes to an imported package which I would like to test, where with `%run` everything is reflected immediately.

Answer (score 0):

`%run` executes a file, as if you were running it on the command line via the `python` command

`import` does what it says, it imports the module into your current notebook, allowing you to use code found in the imported module.

From the sounds of it, since you want to *import* settings, creating a module that has a function that initialises your settings is probably best, sinc eit's more "pythonic" than running a file beforehand.

Comment: `%run` loads all variables into my interactive namespace for further use. If I have an `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` in my script, I can use `plt` later on, in my notebook. So... I'm not that sure.

Comment: I mean, it's entirely up to you. You asked what the difference is between `%run` and `import` and asked for advice and I did that. But it seems as though your mind is already made up because when I gave by 2 cents you defended the opposing position. I don't know what you're using it for or what is easier for you so just do what *you* think is best.

Comment: > "I'd like to import some settings (say, for Matplotlib), for multiple notebooks" I'm new to the IPython and Python environments, so I asked for advice, even though I may have an opinion.

Comment: It still depends. How many imports are there that you don't want to repeat in the notebook? What is your tolerance for manually importing things? For me, it would have to be a lot of imports to justify using `%run` as I would prefer importing them into the notebook manually and use a module for the rest. From what I can tell, this is the only factor in using `%run` instead of `import` so this is what you need to decide. You are free to agree or disagree with my opinion. Hence why I reiterated that it is your choice.

Comment: `%run` is some what like `import ... *`, but it also runs the `if __name...` block.  It's most useful if you want to run a script and then iteract with the data after; somewhat like the `-i` option for a regular Python run.